# How to count how many times of a WORD occurs in a List?

Tags: prolog

How to count how many times of a WORD occurs in a List?

For example:
`counthowmany(hello,[hello,how,are,you,hello,hello],N)`.

`N` gives the total number of word `hello` occurs.

Thanks

Comment: This smells of homework.

Comment: this smells of a reasonable question that as any other deserves an answer.

Comment: UGH*, prolog... i remember doing the wolf, goat, cabbage problem in this as an assignment... OH the memories of pain!

Comment: I think there is no for loop in prolog, it has to be recursion

Comment: Which language are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution:

```
counthowmany(_, [], 0) :- !.
counthowmany(X, [X|Q], N) :- !, counthowmany(X, Q, N1), N is N1+1.
counthowmany(X, [_|Q], N) :- counthowmany(X, Q, N).
```

The first line is the termination test: on an empty list, the count is zero. The two other lines are the recursive calls, and if the first element matches (line 2), the count is incremented.

Here is a similar but purely logical version (no cut), as suggested by Darius:

```
counthowmany(_, [], 0).
counthowmany(X, [X|Q], N) :- counthowmany(X, Q, N1), N is N1+1.
counthowmany(X, [Y|Q], N) :- X \== Y, counthowmany(X, Q, N).
```

Comment: I would've written it without any cuts, using a not-equals test in the last clause instead, since purely-logical definitions are less error-prone to use.

Comment: Preserve [tag:logical-purity] by using `dif/2` instead of `(\==)/2`! More info on `dif` is here: [tag:prolog-dif]

Answer (score 1):

Use the [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`tcount/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29960878/4609915) in tandem with reified term equality [`(=)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29432897/4609915) like this:

```
?- tcount(=(hello),[hello,how,are,you,hello,hello],N).
N = 3.                          % succeeds deterministically
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an alternate implementation. This is Tail recursive using accumulators.

```
countwords(X,L,N) :- countwords(X,L,0,N),!.
countwords(X,[],N,N).
countwords(X,[X|T],P,N) :- P1 is P+1 , countwords(X,T,P1,N).
countwords(X,[H|T],P,N) :- X\==H , countwords(X,T,P,N).
```

Answer (score -1):

An even better aswer

```
countWord([],0).
countWord([_|List], A):- countWord(List,B), A is B+1.
```