# Remove duplicates in list (Prolog)

Tags: list, prolog

I am completely new to Prolog and trying some exercises. One of them is:

> Write a predicate set(InList,OutList)
>   which takes as input an arbitrary
>   list, and returns a list in which each
>   element of the input list appears only
>   once.

Here is my solution:

```
member(X,[X|_]).
member(X,[_|T]) :- member(X,T).

set([],[]).
set([H|T],[H|Out]) :-
    not(member(H,T)),
    set(T,Out).
set([H|T],Out) :-
    member(H,T),
    set(T,Out).
```

I'm not allowed to use any of built-in predicates (It would be better even do not use `not/1`). The problem is, that `set/2` gives multiple *same* solutions. The more repetitions in the input list, the more solutions will result. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: if You'd be allowed to use built-in predicates, in SWI ```list_to_set``` , ```sort``` worked for me to deduplicate, both have only one solution each. Ok, it's not asked here. So ignore plse.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are getting multiple solutions due to Prolog's backtracking. Technically, each solution provided is correct, which is why it is being generated. If you want just one solution to be generated, you are going to have to stop backtracking at some point. This is what the Prolog [cut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_%28logic_programming%29) is used for. You might find that reading up on that will help you with this problem.

Update: Right. Your `member()` predicate is evaluating as `true` in several different ways if the first variable is in multiple positions in the second variable.

I've used the name `mymember()` for this predicate, so as not to conflict with GNU Prolog's builtin `member()` predicate. My knowledge base now looks like this:

```
mymember(X,[X|_]).
mymember(X,[_|T]) :- mymember(X,T).

not(A) :- \+ call(A).

set([],[]).
set([H|T],[H|Out]) :-
    not(mymember(H,T)),
    set(T,Out).
set([H|T],Out) :-
    mymember(H,T),
    set(T,Out).
```

So, `mymember(1, [1, 1, 1]).` evaluates as `true` in three different ways:

```
| ?- mymember(1, [1, 1, 1]).

true ? a

true

true

no
```

If you want to have only one answer, you're going to have to use a cut. Changing the first definition of `mymember()` to this:

```
mymember(X,[X|_]) :- !.
```

Solves your problem.

Furthermore, you can avoid `not()` altogether, if you wish, by defining a `notamember()` predicate yourself. The choice is yours.

Comment: The cuts discussed in the end of the book. I haven't read about them yet. So, if this predicate gives multiple same answers and all of them is right, technically, I solved this exercise? :)

Comment: OK, my Prolog's rusty, and I don't have an environment to hand, but I can't see how you're getting multiple results in this particular case. I'm assuming that you're calling set() with the first variable bound and the second unbound. In this case, I would expect set() to produce multiple values for the second variable only if not() or member() produced multiple results, and I'm not convinced that either would. Follow evaluation through step-by-step to see where your multiple results come from, and you'll get a bit more of an insight than I can offer you at the moment into what's happening.

Comment: I've now found and installed GNU Prolog, and it doesn't have a `not()` predicate. Could you outline how your `not()` predicate is defined?

Comment: Thank you, now I understand *why* it gets multiple answers! :)

Comment: Thank you Tim for your help. I learnt a practical use of the operator \+ and also I used the cut operator because of multiple responses too.

Answer (score 7):

A simpler (and likely faster) solution is to use library predicate sort/2 which remove duplicates in O(n log n). Definitely works in Yap prolog and SWIPL

Comment: The goal here is to learn prolog, not to learn how to use library functions ;)

Comment: Just a foot note: this method simply works :) Though it have some side effect, use it if your goal is just to find a list of results where order doesn't matter :)

Comment: @Pierre-LouisGottfrois I was looking for something else but I need to say that: no one has mastered a programming language by reimplementing **poorly** library predicates. No wonder the majority of students hate Prolog.

Comment: @user1812457 who said "No wonder the majority of students hate Prolog" as **poor** argument.  On the contrary, I would say that if it is true that the majority of student hates Prolog, it a very good signal of the intellectual interest of this programming language.

Answer (score 7):

You are on the right track... **Stay pure**---it's easy!

Use reified equality predicates `=/3` and `dif/3` in combination with `if_/3`, as implemented in [Prolog union for A U B U C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358456/prolog-union-for-a-u-b-u-c):

```
=(X, Y, R) :- X == Y,    !, R = true.
=(X, Y, R) :- ?=(X, Y),  !, R = false. % syntactically different
=(X, Y, R) :- X \= Y,    !, R = false. % semantically different
=(X, Y, R) :- R == true, !, X = Y.
=(X, X, true).
=(X, Y, false) :-
   dif(X, Y).

% dif/3 is defined like (=)/3
dif(X, Y, R) :- X == Y,    !, R = false.
dif(X, Y, R) :- ?=(X, Y),  !, R = true. % syntactically different
dif(X, Y, R) :- X \= Y,    !, R = true. % semantically different
dif(X, Y, R) :- R == true, !, X \= Y.
dif(X, Y, true) :-         % succeed first!
   dif(X, Y).
dif(X, X, false).

if_(C_1, Then_0, Else_0) :-
   call(C_1, Truth),
   functor(Truth,_,0),  % safety check
   ( Truth == true -> Then_0 ; Truth == false, Else_0 ).
```

Based on these predicates we build a reified membership predicate `list_item_isMember/3`. It is semantically equivalent with `memberd_truth/3` by @false. We rearrange the argument order so the list is the 1st argument. This enables *first-argument* indexing which prevents leaving useless choice-points behind as `memberd_truth/3` would create.

```
list_item_isMember([],_,false).
list_item_isMember([X|Xs],E,Truth) :-
   if_(E = X, Truth = true, list_item_isMember(Xs,E,Truth)).

list_set([],[]).
list_set([X|Xs],Ys) :-
    if_(list_item_isMember(Xs,X), Ys = Ys0, Ys = [X|Ys0]),
    list_set(Xs,Ys0).
```

A simple query shows that *all redundant answers have been eliminated* and that the goal succeeds *without leaving any choice-points behind*:

```
?- list_set([1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2,1],Xs).
Xs = [4,3,2,1].                         % succeeds deterministically
```

---

#### Edit 2015-04-23

I was inspired by @Ludwig's answer of `set/2`, which goes like this:

```
set([],[]).
set([H|T],[H|T1]) :- subtract(T,[H],T2), set(T2,T1).
```

SWI-Prolog's builtin predicate `subtract/3` can be non-monotone, which may restrict its use. `list_item_subtracted/3` is a **monotone** variant of it:

```
list_item_subtracted([],_,[]).
list_item_subtracted([A|As],E,Bs1) :-
    if_(dif(A,E), Bs1 = [A|Bs], Bs = Bs1),
    list_item_subtracted(As,E,Bs).
```

`list_setB/2` is like `set/2`, but is based on `list_item_subtracted/3`---not `subtract/3`:

```
list_setB([],[]).
list_setB([X|Xs1],[X|Ys]) :-
    list_item_subtracted(Xs1,X,Xs),
    list_setB(Xs,Ys).
```

The following queries compare `list_set/2` and `list_setB/2`:

```
?- list_set([1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2,1], Xs).
Xs = [4,3,2,1].                          % succeeds deterministically
?- list_setB([1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2,1],Xs).
Xs = [1,2,3,4].                          % succeeds deterministically

?- list_set(Xs,[a,b]).
   Xs = [a,b]
;  Xs = [a,b,b]
;  Xs = [a,b,b,b] 
...                                      % does not terminate universally
?- list_setB(Xs,[a,b]).
   Xs = [a,b]
;  Xs = [a,b,b]
;  Xs = [a,b,b,b]
...                                      % does not terminate universally
```

Comment: Why is there is choice point open (in the final query)? Seems `memberd_truth/2` needs a better implementation.

Answer (score 5):

I think that a better way to do this would be:

```
set([], []).
set([H|T], [H|T1]) :- subtract(T, [H], T2), set(T2, T1).
```

So, for example `?- set([1,4,1,1,3,4],S)` give you as output:

```
S = [1, 4, 3]
```

Comment: Yes, the code is for SWI-Prolog... and thanks for value my solution.

Comment: speaking to yourself? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Adding my answer to this old thread:

```
notmember(_,[]).
notmember(X,[H|T]):-X\=H,notmember(X,T).

set([],[]).
set([H|T],S):-set(T,S),member(H,S).
set([H|T],[H|S]):-set(T,S),not(member(H,S)).
```

The *only virtue* of this solution is that it uses only those predicates that have been introduced by the point where this exercise appears in the [original text](http://[1]:%20http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse27).

Answer (score 0):

This works without cut, but it needs more lines and another argument. 
If I change the [H2|T2] to S on line three, it will produce multiple results. I don't understand why.

```
setb([],[],_).
setb([H|T],[H|T2],A) :- not(member(H,A)),setb(T,T2,[H|A]).
setb([H|T],[H2|T2],A) :- member(H,A),setb(T,[H2|T2],A).
setb([H|T],[],A) :- member(H,A),setb(T,[],A).
set(L,S) :- setb(L,S,[]).
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to stop the backtracking of Prolog.

```
enter code here
member(X,[X|_]):- !.
member(X,[_|T]) :- member(X,T).

set([],[]).
set([H|T],[H|Out]) :-
   not(member(H,T)),
   !,
set(T,Out).
set([H|T],Out) :-
   member(H,T),
   set(T,Out).
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the support function `mymember` of Tim, you can do this if the order of elements in the set isn't important:

```
mymember(X,[X|_]).
mymember(X,[_|T]) :- mymember(X,T).

mkset([],[]).
mkset([T|C], S) :- mymember(T,C),!, mkset(C,S).
mkset([T|C], S) :- mkset(C,Z), S=[T|Z].
```

So, for example `?- mkset([1,4,1,1,3,4],S)` give you as output:

```
S = [1, 3, 4]
```

but, if you want a set with the elements ordered like in the list you can use:

```
mkset2([],[], _).
mkset2([T|C], S, D) :- mkset2(C,Z,[T|D]), ((mymember(T,D), S=Z,!) ; S=[T|Z]).
mkset(L, S) :- mkset2(L,S,[]).
```

This solution, with the same input of the previous example, give to you:

```
S = [1, 4, 3]
```

This time the elements are in the same order as they appear in the input list.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Remove duplicates from a list without accumulator */
our_member(A,[A|Rest]).
our_member(A, [_|Rest]):-
    our_member(A, Rest).

remove_dup([],[]):-!.
remove_dup([X|Rest],L):-
    our_member(X,Rest),!,
    remove_dup(Rest,L).
remove_dup([X|Rest],[X|L]):-
    remove_dup(Rest,L).
```

Comment: @rkta this isn't an optimized solution. It will work efficiently for smaller lists,but as the length of list increases,search space becomes larger. We can optimize it using accumulator.