# Prolog - extract elements in two List

Tags: prolog

I have a problem, i have two lists, and i want to extract all of elements that are the same. For example :

```
> comparer([la_defense,etoile,chatelet,nation],[auber,chatelet,hotel_de_ville,nation],X).

comparer([],LSB,LI).
comparer([X|LS],LSB,LI):-member(X,LSB),!,comparer(LS,LSB,[LI|X]).
comparer([X|LS],LSB,LI):-comparer(LS,LSB,LI).
```

I want this result :

```
X = [chatelet,nation].
```

But this code i made doesn't works. i'm a newbie so... what is the problem ? :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an accumlator, so the code should be

```
comparer(L1, L2, R) :-
    comparer(L1, L2, [], R).

comparer([], _, R, LR) :-
    reverse(R, LR).

comparer([X|LS],LSB,LI, R):-
    member(X,LSB),!,
    comparer(LS,LSB,[X | LI], R).
comparer([_X|LS],LSB,LI, R):-
    comparer(LS,LSB,LI, R).
```

You can try this

```
comparer([], _, []).

comparer([X|LS],LSB,LI):-
    comparer(LS, LSB, R),
    (   member(X, LSB) -> LI = [X | R]; LI = R).
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly ^^ so if member is true, LI = [X | R ]... is executed ? i didn't know "->" :/

Answer (score 2):

[intersection](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=intersection/3)/3 does exactly what you need.

```
?- intersection([la_defense,etoile,chatelet,nation],[auber,chatelet,hotel_de_ville,nation],X).
X = [chatelet, nation].
```

Comment: I don't see what you want to explain ?

Comment: just in case you were not aware of the library available...IMO make sense, because @joel76 already addressed the problem in your code

Answer (score 1):

[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29819232/4609915) to the similar question [Intersection and union of 2 lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9615002/intersection-and-union-of-2-lists) might be of interest to you.

Unlike other answers posted here and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9615002/intersection-and-union-of-2-lists), the implementation I suggest is logically pure and monotone, which makes it more versatile and robust with regard to generalization / specialization.

First, let's see if it works with the query you gave above:

```
?- As = [la_defense,etoile,chatelet,nation],
   Bs = [auber,chatelet,hotel_de_ville,nation],
   list_list_intersection(As,Bs,Xs).
As = [la_defense, etoile, chatelet, nation],
Bs = [auber, chatelet, hotel_de_ville, nation],
Xs = [chatelet, nation].
```

But what if we write the query in a different (but logically equivalent) way?

```
?- As = [_,_,_,_],
   Bs = [_,_,_,_],
   list_list_intersection(As,Bs,Xs),
   As = [la_defense,etoile,chatelet,nation],
   Bs = [auber,chatelet,hotel_de_ville,nation].
As = [la_defense, etoile, chatelet, nation],
Bs = [auber, chatelet, hotel_de_ville, nation],
Xs = [chatelet, nation].
```

With `list_list_intersection/3` we get the **same result**.

---

Now, let us consider using the builtin `intersection/3`, which was proposed in another answer. Is `intersection/3` robust regarding generalization, too?

```
?- As = [_,_,_,_],
   Bs = [_,_,_,_],
   intersection(As,Bs,Xs),
   As = [la_defense,etoile,chatelet,nation],
   Bs = [auber,chatelet,hotel_de_ville,nation].
false.
```

**No!** `intersection/3` fails, even though it succeeded in a logically equivalent query, which shows that the implementation of `intersection/3` is *not monotone*.

**Bottom line:** `intersection/3` is **harder to use right** than `list_list_intersection/3`; it forces you to think about declarative **and** procedural aspects when using it.