# Prolog , Append with no repititions

Tags: prolog, append, member

Hey I'm trying to append two list with no "double" members

for example

```
A = [a, b, c]
B = [x, c, q]
```

then ->

```
append2(A,B,P)

P= [a,b,c,x,q]
```

I write this code, but it doesn't work...

```
not_member(_, []).
not_member(X, [Y|Ys]) :- X \= Y, not_member(X, Ys).

append2(A, [], A).
append2([], A, A).
append2([h1|ls], B, [h1|P]) :- not_member(h1, B), !, append2(ls, B, P).
append2([h1|ls], B, P) :-  member(h1, P), append2(ls, B, P).
```

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: One major problem is that you are using atoms instead of variables. `h1` is an atom (not variable). `H1` would be a variable (begins with a capital letter). Same for your `ls`. You need `LS` or `Ls`. Fix that and see how far you get. Also it's not clear why you had to define `not_member`. In your `append2` you could just use `\+ member(...)`. At the very least, you could define `not_member(X, L) :- \+ member(X, L).`.

Comment: Hey , I did the changes , no for:
append2([a,b,c] , [c] , P).
I got:
P = [a, b, c] .
But for bigger input like:
append2([a,b,c] , [b,x,a,u] , P).
I got:
ERROR: Out of global stack

Comment: That means you have circular logic in your code somewhere. Looks like @gusbro handed you an rewrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there are no variables in your input lists, but allowing duplicates in each list you may write:

```
append2(A,B,C):-
  findall(Item, append2_item(A,B,Item), C).

append2_item(A,_,ItemA):-
  append(HeadA, [ItemA|_], A),
  \+ member(ItemA, HeadA).
append2_item(A,B,ItemB):-
  append(HeadB, [ItemB|_], B),
  \+ member(ItemB, HeadB),
  \+ member(ItemB, A).
```

First clause of `append2_item/3` selects (ordered) distinct items from the first list. Second clause of `append2_item/3` selects (ordered) distinct items from the second list which are not present in the first list.
`append2/3` just collects those elements.

Test case:

```
?- append2([a,b,c,a],[x,c,q,x],C).
C = [a, b, c, x, q].
```

Comment: @Kika: [findall/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=findall/3) collects the first argument (template) from executing the goal from the second argument (with backtracking to test all solutions) and unifies the third argument with the list of collected templates.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the **pure** code in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29819232/4609915)
to the related question "[intersection and union of 2 lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9615002/intersection-and-union-of-2-lists)"!

Telling from your requirements, predicate `list_list_union/3` is just what you are looking for:

```
?- list_list_union([a,b,c],[x,c,q],Ls).
Ls = [a,b,c,x,q].                               % succeeds deterministically
```

`list_list_union/3` is **monotone**, so we get *sound answers* 
even when using non-ground terms:

```
?- As = [_,_,_], Bs = [_,_,_], list_list_union(As,Bs,Ls), As = [a,b,c], Bs = [x,c,q].
As = [a,b,c], Bs = [x,c,q], Ls = [a,b,c,x,q] ;  % logically sound result
false.
```