# Using Prolog to find Intersecting Lists

Tags: prolog, intersection

I'm having trouble trying to debug this code of mine to find the intersection between two lists...

For Example:
`List1 = [3, 4, 5, 6]` and 
`List2 = [5, 1, 0, 2, 4]`.

So, the intersecting lines would be stored into `List3` would be `[4, 5]`.

So here's the code for Prolog.

Any help would be appreciated!!!

```
setIntersection([], [], []).
setIntersection([], _, []).

setIntersection([X|Xs], Y, [Z|W]) :-
    keepDuplicates(X, Y, [Z|Zs]),
    setIntersection(Xs, Y, W).

keepDuplicates(_, [], []).
keepDuplicates([], _, []).
keepDuplicates([], [], []).

% Check if the head of the first list is not a match to the
% first head of the second list
keepDuplicates(G, [H|Hs], Line) :-
    G \= H,
    keepDuplicates(G, Hs, Line).

% Check if the head of the first list
% Does match to the head of the second list
keepDuplicates(G, [G|Gs], [G|NewLine]) :-
    keepDuplicates(G, Gs, NewLine).
```

Comment: It is probably easier to sort both lists first; look here (http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/home/vnc/prolog/lib/swipl/library/ordsets.pl?show=src#ord_intersect/2) for a very idiomatic solution to finding the intersection of ordered lists.

Comment: I agree with @Boris. If you are treating lists as sets, and since sets are "unordered", then you should be able to use a list ordering that is an advantage in handling.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a couple of logically pure, monotone implementations of list intersection and union in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29819232/4609915) to the related question "[Intersection and union of 2 lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9615002/intersection-and-union-of-2-lists)".

Let's see a sample query:

```
?- list_list_intersection([3,4,5,6],[5,1,0,2,4],Intersection).
Intersection = [4,5].             % succeeds deterministically
```

As the proposed implementation is **monotone**, you can also use it in more general ways and still get **logically sound answers**:

```
?- L2 = [_,_,_], list_list_intersection([3,4,5,6],L2,[4,5]).
L2 = [ 4, 5,_A], dif(_A,6), dif(_A,3)                      ;
L2 = [ 4,_A, 5], dif(_A,6), dif(_A,5), dif(_A,3)           ;
L2 = [ 5, 4,_A], dif(_A,6), dif(_A,3)                      ;
L2 = [_A, 4, 5], dif(_A,6), dif(_A,5), dif(_A,4),dif(_A,3) ;
L2 = [ 5,_A, 4], dif(_A,6), dif(_A,4), dif(_A,3)           ;
L2 = [_A, 5, 4], dif(_A,6), dif(_A,5), dif(_A,4),dif(_A,3) ;
false.
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually `sets` in Prolog are represented with sorted lists, then avoiding the *ambiguity* of the representation that arises in presence of duplicate elements. Let's ignore this problem...

This fact `setIntersection([], [], []).` is *subsumed* by `setIntersection([], _, []).`, then can (should!) be deleted.
The same for `keepDuplicates([], [], []).` (why do you invert clauses order here ?)

You have a singleton Zs: `...,keepDuplicates(X, Y, [Z|Zs]),...` and you should pay attention to that warning (of course, if your compiler display it), since it's often symptom of a true mistake.

Also, that predicate cannot cover all the cases: when X is *not* in Y, what do you associate to Z ?

To be true, I think you're doing it more complicated than required. Ignoring duplicates, the whole could be easy as

```
?- L1=[3,4,5,6],L2=[5,1,0,2,4],findall(C, (member(C,L1),memberchk(C,L2)), I).
```