# Return a list from items matching in two lists Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, matching

I am very new to Prolog and I have this :

```
compare_list(Hours1, Hours2, Matching)
```

I want to return the matching hours between lists Hours1 and Hours2 into the list Matching

I can get the matches but not construct the list of matches.

> Hours1 may be like: [1,2,3],
>   Hours2 may be like: [2,3],
>   So from this:
>   Matching Hours should be: [2,3]

Help would be appreciated.

I have implemented what Vennik has suggested and it is very near to what I want.
Results From Hours1 : [2,3,5], Hours2 : [2,5]
Give the following:

```
Matching = [2, 5] ;
Matching = [2] ;
Matching = [5] ;
Matching = []
```

Is it possible to only have the first set without producing the other three results?

Comment: Can you show your attempt thus far?

Comment: So a list of hours is just an ordered list of integers? As C.B. mentioned, please show what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
compare_list([], _, []).
compare_list([Hour | Hours1], Hours2, [Hour | Matching]) :-
    member(Hour, Hours2),
    compare_list(Hours1, Hours2, Matching).
compare_list([_ | Hours1], Hours2, Matching) :-
    compare_list(Hours1, Hours2, Matching).
```

Calling `compare_list([1,2,3], [1,2], X), !.` will result in `X = [1,2]`.

Comment: Nearly perfect. Have edited original to show the result and what I would like if possible.

Comment: That is perfect for what I need, Thanks

Comment: In Prolog it is good practise to **always** put the responsibility regarding the use of `(!)/0` to the "callee", not the "caller". Your previous version was better.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider the related question [intersection and union of 2 lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9615002/intersection-and-union-of-2-lists).

In particular, my [logically pure answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29819232/4609915) to above question might be of good use to you, as it offers *multiple advantages* over the code posted by @vennik above:

1. The predicates behave the way relations should. "Multi-directional."
2. They are monotone and remain sound upon arbitrary generalization / specialization.
3. They aim at completeness of the relation of interest, creating choice points when required.
4. They are efficient, avoiding the creation of useless choice points.

Answer (score 0):

I know that is not *pure*... (or not *montone*, if you like) ... but, if you aren't a *purist*, SWI-Prolog give you the predicate

```
intersection/3
```

that you can use in this way

```
intersection(Hours1, Hours2, Matching).
```

Comment: @repeat: This is a big True!