# Intersection of two lists without duplicate elements in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, duplicates

I need to write a program that finds the intersection of two lists. I can't use cuts and there shouldn't be any duplicate elements in the result list.

This is my code:

```
intersection([],_,[]).
intersection([X|Xs],Y,[X|Zs]) :-
    member(X,Y),
    intersection(Xs,Y,Zs).
intersection([_|Xs],Y,Zs) :-
    intersection(Xs,Y,Zs).
```

When I run the following query, I get these answers:

```
?- intersection([a,b,c,a],[a,v,c],L).
L = [a, c, a] ;
L = [a, c] ;            % <---------- this is only answer I want to get
L = [a, a] ;
L = [a] ;
L = [c, a] ;
L = [c] ;
L = [a] ;
L = [].
```

What can I do? I want to get `L = [a,c]` and nothing else... Can you help?

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you mean by "conjunction". Do you mean "intersection"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29819232/4609915) to the related question "[Intersection and union of 2 lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9615002/intersection-and-union-of-2-lists)" I presented the logically pure predicate `list_list_intersectionSet/3`. It should fit your requirements to a T!

Here's is a brushed-up version of `list_list_intersectionSet/3`, which is based on:

- monotone conditional [`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915),
- [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`tfilter/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29963476/4609915),
- and the reified test predicates [`dif/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867514/4609915) and [`memberd_t/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29963476/4609915).

Here we go:

```
list_list_intersectionSet([]     ,_ ,[]).
list_list_intersectionSet([A|As0],Bs,Cs0) :-
   if_(memberd_t(A,Bs), Cs0 = [A|Cs], Cs0 = Cs),
   tfilter(dif(A),As0,As), 
   list_list_intersectionSet(As,Bs,Cs).
```

Let's see it in action!

```
?- list_list_intersectionSet([a,b,c,a],[a,v,c],L).
L = [a,c].
```

Comment: Good to see a solution that produces correct answers.

Comment: @repeat Is there a way to rewrite this to avoid using "dif" and "member_t" I'm attempting to get this working using only the simplest commands

Answer (score 3):

If by "conjunction" you mean "intersection", you should take a look at the implementation in the SWI-Prolog [`library(lists)`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=lists) of the predicate [`intersection/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/home/swipl/lib/swipl/library/lists.pl?show=src#intersection/3). It contains cuts, but you can leave them out if you don't mind all the choicepoints.

With it:

```
?- intersection([a,b,c,a],[a,v,c],I).
I = [a, c, a].
```

Of course, this doesn't work even in the library predicate, because you need *sets* with your current definition. (It is enough if only the first argument is a set.)

You can make sets with the `sort/2` predicate: if the first argument is a list with repetitions, the second argument will be a sorted list without repetitions, for example:

```
?- sort([a,b,c,a], S1), intersection(S1, [a,v,c], I).
S1 = [a, b, c],
I = [a, c].
```

or maybe:

```
?- sort([a,b,c,a], S1), intersection(S1, [a,v,c,c,a,c], I).
S1 = [a, b, c],
I = [a, c].

?- sort([a,b,c,a,b,c,a,b,c], S1), intersection(S1, [a,v,c,c,a,c], I).
S1 = [a, b, c],
I = [a, c].
```

If you sort both arguments, you can use a [`ord_intersection/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=ord_intersection/3) from [`library(ordsets)`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/oset.pl), implemented in terms of [`oset_int/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/oset.pl?show=src#oset_int/3).

```
?- sort([a,b,c,a], S1), sort([a,v,c,c,a,c], S2), ord_intersection(S1, S2, I).
S1 = [a, b, c],
S2 = [a, c, v],
I = [a, c].
```

Importantly, `oset_int/3` does not use any cuts in its implementation. It however assumes that the first and second arguments are lists of elements sorted by the ["standard order of terms"](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=compare) and without duplicates, as done by `sort/2`.

If for some reason you don't want to use `sort/2`, you could maybe use an accumulator and check against it before taking an element to the intersection:

```
my_intersection(Xs, Ys, Zs) :-
    my_intersection_1(Xs, Ys, [], Zs).
my_intersection_1([], _, Zs, Zs).
my_intersection_1([X|Xs], Ys, Zs0, Zs) :-
    member(X, Ys), \+ member(X, Zs0),
    my_intersection_1(Xs, Ys, [X|Zs0], Zs).
my_intersection_1([_|Xs], Ys, Zs0, Zs) :-
    my_intersection_1(Xs, Ys, Zs0, Zs).
```

Of course, the order of the elements in the result will be now reversed. If this is not what you mean by "conjunction", you could for example rewrite the first two clauses of `my_intersection_1/4` as:

```
my_intersection_1([], _, _, []).
my_intersection_1([X|Xs], Ys, Zs0, [X|Zs]) :-
    member(X, Ys), \+ member(X, Zs0),
    my_intersection_1(Xs, Ys, [X|Zs0], Zs).
```

Comment: You answer  is incorrect for "insufficiently instantiated terms".

Comment: @false Yes, it is not correct for "insufficiently instantiated terms".

Comment: How do you expect a beginner to understand when the term is not sufficiently instantiated?

Answer (score 3):

The previously shown [`list_list_intersectionSet/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31669255/4609915) *restricts* the item order in the intersection:

```
?- list_list_intersectionSet([a,b],[a,b], [a,b]).
true.

?- list_list_intersectionSet([a,b],[a,b], [b,a]).
false.
```

In this answer we lift that restriction... preserving [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity) **and** determinism (for ground cases)!

First, we define `none_intersect/2` using [Prolog lambdas](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord) and 
[meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`maplist/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/4609915).

`none_intersect(As,Bs)` states that all members in `As` are different from all members in `Bs`.

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

none_intersect(As,Bs) :-
   maplist(\A^maplist(dif(A),Bs),As).
```

Next, we define `intersection_of_and/3`---based on `none_intersect/2` (defined above), [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`tpartition/4`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867514/4609915) and reified term equality [`(=)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915):

```
intersection_of_and([],As,Bs) :-
   none_intersect(As,Bs).
intersection_of_and([X|Xs],As0,Bs0) :-
   tpartition(=(X),As0,[_|_],As),        % [_|_] = [X|_]
   tpartition(=(X),Bs0,[_|_],Bs),        % [_|_] = [X|_]
   intersection_of_and(Xs,As,Bs).
```

`intersection_of_and(Xs,As,Bs)` states that

- all items which occur in both `As` and `Bs` also occur in `Xs` (first clause),
- all items in `Xs` occur in both `As` and `Bs` at least once (second clause),
- and the list `Xs` does not contain any duplicates.

`intersection_of_and/3` uses a specific argument in order to enable first argument indexing.

Last, we define `list_list_intersection/3` which has the argument order that the OP used:

```
list_list_intersection(As,Bs,Xs) :-
   intersection_of_and(Xs,As,Bs).
```

Let's run some queries! First, the query that the bounty offerer suggested:

```
?- list_list_intersection([a,b],[a,b], [b,a]).
true.
```

Next, a similar query with 3 distinct items in 3 lists having 3 different orders:

```
?- list_list_intersection([a,b,c],[b,a,c], [c,a,b]).
true.
```

What if some `x` only occurs in the first/second list?

```
?- list_list_intersection([a,b,c,x],[b,a,c], [c,a,b]).
true.

?- list_list_intersection([a,b,c],[b,a,c,x], [c,a,b]).
true.
```

What if some item occurs twice in the first/second list?

```
?- list_list_intersection([a,b,c],[b,a,c,b], [c,a,b]).
true.

?- list_list_intersection([a,b,c,c],[b,a,c], [c,a,b]).
true.
```

Last, what if the intersection contains duplicates? 
Intersections *are not* to contain duplicates...

```
?- list_list_intersection([a,b,c],[b,a,c], [c,c,a,b]).
false.                                     % as expected
```

Comment: What about termination properties?

Comment: @false. Now, that's what I want to know, too! Will investivate and edit the answer.  `cti` FTW, I hope:)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like something like this would be the easy way:

```
intersection( Xs , Ys , Zs ) :-
  sort(Xs,X1)     , % order and de-dupe the 1st list so as to produce a set
  sort(Ys,Y1)     , % order and de-dupe the 2nd list so as to produce a set
  merge(Xs,Ys,Zs)   % merge the two [ordered] sets to produce the result
  .                 % easy!

merge( []     , []     , []     ) .
merge( []     , [_|_]  , []     ) .
merge( [_|_]  , []     , []     ) .
merge( [X|Xs] , [Y|Ys] , [X|Zs] ) :- X =  Y , merge(    Xs  ,    Ys  , Zs ) .
merge( [X|Xs] , [Y|Ys] , Zs     ) :- X <  Y , merge(    Xs  , [Y|Ys] , Zs ) .
merge( [X|Xs] , [Y|Ys] , Zs     ) :- X >  Y , merge( [X|Xs] ,    Ys  , Zs ) .
```

Or even just this [not-terribly-performant] one-liner:

```
intersection( Xs , Ys , Zs ) :- setof(Z,(member(Z,Xs),member(Z,Ys)),Zs).
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by simple set theory:

```
    intersection(A,B,AnB):-
        subtract(A,B,AminusB),
        subtract(A,AminusB,K),
        sort(K,AnB).
```

For the query:

```
   ?- intersection([a,b,c,a],[a,v,c],L).
```

output is

```
    L = [a, c].
```

No more answers.