# Finding all the matching elements in 2 lists in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I have to write a Prolog program that finds all the matching elements between 2 separate lists. In practice it has to look like this:

```
?- intersect([a,c,a,b], [d,b,a,b], X).

X = [a,b]
```

What i have so far is this:

```
intersect([], Y, Z).
intersect([H| T1], Y, [H| T2]) :-
   member(H, Y),
   remove_all(H, T1, P),
   intersect(T1, Y, T2).
intersect([H| T1], Y, T2) :-
   intersect(T1, Y, T2).
```

(I had to make a remove_all function in a previous exercise. This removes all the elements from a list that match what you give)

This works except for one thing, my answer looks like this:

```
X = [a, b|_17660]
```

I'm new to Prolog and don't know that much about it. Why is there a "|_17660" at the end and how would i change my code to fix it?
If someone could help me with this that would be appreciated.

Comment: What would you want as a result for `intersect([a,b,c,d,e,f], [a,b,x,y,d,e,f,m], X).`?

Comment: Where is your `remove_all/3`? You assume it's correct, ...

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you got three clean warnings about "singleton variables".  That is a very clear hint that something went wrong. Usually, a Prolog programmer would fix that first. But of course, there are other ways, too.

So your problem is that you get `X = [a, b|_17660]` as an answer. What does this mean? The `_176660` is just a variable name which has to be quantified universally. In other words the answer you got reads:

> All `X` that start with `[a, b|_]` are a solution. Like `[a, b]` which is intended, but also ugly ones like `[a, b|non_list]`. Or even misleading or even incorrect ones like `[a, b, c]`.

To understand where this problem comes from, lets focus on an implied ground query, like:

```
?- intersect([a,c,a,b], [d,b,a,b], [a,b|non_list]).
   existence_error(procedure,remove_all/3). % ERROR: Undefined procedure: remove_all/3
```

Argh, you did not show the definition of `remove_all/3`.  In a traditional programming language, we would have to stop now. But in Prolog, we still can continue. No need to see that definition. I will instead use a **specialization** that no longer contains `remove_all/3`.  So in a sense, this is only part of your program, but we can still draw conclusions from it.  This is what I use:

```
intersect([], Y, Z) :- Z = non_list.
intersect([H| T1], Y, [H| T2]) :- false,
   member(H, Y),
   remove_all(H, T1, P),
   intersect(T1, Y, T2).
intersect([H| T1], Y, T2) :- T2 = non_list,
   intersect(T1, Y, T2).
```

This program is almost yours. Except that I have added extra goals to it. In another language this would not be possible. But in Prolog we can exploit   a very nice property of (pure, monotonic) Prolog programs: You can add extra goals randomly and still predict what the outcome will be: The new program describes a *subset* of what your original program did.  Of course, I had some suspicions, so my adding was somewhat guided. But you can *always* do the same with your buggy program!

Still not convinced? Now use that new program to see what you are actually describing:

```
?- intersect(Xs, Ys, Zs).
   Xs = [], Zs = non_list
;  ... .
?- intersect([], any, non_list).
   true.
```

Clearly, this is not what you intended. To see where that came from, we can specialize your program even more:

```
intersect([], Y, Z) :- Z = non_list.
intersect([H| T1], Y, [H| T2]) :- false,
   member(H, Y),
   remove_all(H, T1, P),
   intersect(T1, Y, T2).
intersect([H| T1], Y, T2) :- false,
   intersect(T1, Y, T2).
```

It should be evident by now, that the fact has to be specialized, otherwise these nonsensical solutions are possible. Here is such a specialization:

```
intersect([], _Y, Z) :-
   Z = [].
intersect([H| T1], Y, [H| T2]) :- false,
   member(H, Y),
   remove_all(H, T1, P),
   intersect(T1, Y, T2).
intersect([H| T1], Y, T2) :-
   intersect(T1, Y, T2).
```

The fact reads: The intersection of the empty list and anything is the empty list. Let's leave it that way, even if `Y = non_list` is now possible, too.

Your rule is still removed, since I have not seen your definition. It does not matter! I will continue to find problems in the remaining program. For the moment, I have no idea, where to look for problems. But I can ask Prolog to do this for me by asking the **most general query** which reads like

> Prolog, just tell me all solutions you can describe.

(Remember this trick, you can always ask that question - without having even the slightest idea what the predicate is about.)

```
?- intersect(Xs, Ys, Zs).
   Xs = [], Zs = []
;  Xs = [_A], Zs = []
;  Xs = [_A,_B], Zs = []
;  ... .
```

The first answer is perfect, but the second answer is not. Note that `Ys` does not occur anywhere, so the answer holds for all `Ys`.  Even:

```
?- intersect([a], [a], []).
   true.
```

This problem is directly related to your rule, there is no condition for it whatsoever ...

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29819232/772868) for a clean solution.