# Why is my predicate not backtracking?

Tags: prolog, backtracking

I don't understand why my predicate doesnt  backtrack and find all solutions.

```
person(john).
person(erik).

allExceptSpider(person(Spider),T ):-
    setof(person(X),person(X),S),
    subtract(S,[person(Spider) ],T).
```

If I call this predicate with Two variables:

```
allExceptSpider(person(Z),Q)
```

Then it will only give me the answer Z = john, Q = [person(erik)]
but it won't backtrack to find Z = erik ,Q = [person(john)]
why?

Comment: Because of subtract/3 signature: +,+,-. The second argument should be ground.

Comment: @CapelliC. Mode specs are sloppy. cf https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/Mode-Spec.html . IIRC "++" is used by some processors to indicate "should be ground".

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR:** If you use [`subtract/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=subtract/3) , your code may lose [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity).

```
person(john).
person(erik).

allExceptSpider(Spider, T) :-
   setof(X, person(X), S),
   subtract(S, [Spider], T).
```

**Preserve purity!** How? Use [`list_item_subtracted/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29432897/4609915) like so:

```
allExceptSpiderNU(Spider, T) :-
   setof(X, person(X), S),
   list_item_subtracted(S, Spider, T).
```

Sample queries head-to-head:

```
?- allExceptSpider(Z, Q).
Q = [erik], Z = john.

?- allExceptSpiderNU(Z,Q).
   Q = [     erik]             ,     Z=john
;  Q = [john     ],     Z=erik
;  Q = [john,erik], dif(Z,erik), dif(Z,john).
```