# Custom subset not backtracking

Tags: prolog, subset

I'm new to prolog and I've been having trouble with some homework.
On some part of my code I have to generate subsets of a given set *on backtracking*. Meaning, the code should try for a subset, and when it fails the next condition, try the next subset. I have done some research and the default function [subset](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=subset/2) won't backtrack because as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37634782/why-is-my-predicate-not-backtracking) question both arguments are [input arguments](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/Mode-Spec.html). So I built a custom one, which still isn't backtracking. Can you give me a hint on what I'm failing on? Here's my code:

```
    numNutrients(8).
    product(milk,[2,4,6]).
    product(porkChops,[1,8]).
    product(yoghurt,[3,1]).
    product(honey,[5,7]).
    product(plastic,[3,5,2]).
    product(magic,[5,7,8]).
```

`nutrientlist(N,L):-findall(I,between(1,N,I),L).

subset2([],[]):-!.
subset2([X|T],[X|T2]):-
    subset2(T,T2).
subset2([_|T],[T2]):-
    subset2(T,T2).

shopping(K,L):-
    numNutrients(J),
    nutrientlist(J,N),
    findall(P,product(P,_),Z),
    subset2(X,Z),
    length(X,T),
    T =< K,
    covers(X,N),
    L = X.

covers(_,[]):-!.
covers([X|L],N):-
    product(X,M),
    subset2(M,N),
    subtract(N,M,T),
    covers(L,T).

main:-
    shopping(5,L),
    write(L).`

The problem is on predicate shopping(K,L). When it gets to predicate subset2, it gives the whole set, which has length 6 (not 5), then fails and doesn't backtrack. Since all previous predicates can't backtrack it just fails.

So, why doesn't subset2 backtrack?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Primary focus: `subset2/2`

First, let us focus *only* on the predicate that shows different properties from those you expect.

In your case, this is *only* `subset2/2`, defined by you as:

```
subset2([], []) :- !.
subset2([X|T], [X|T2]) :-
        subset2(T, T2).
subset2([_|T], [T2]) :-
        subset2(T, T2).
```

I will now use **declarative debugging** to locate the cause of the problem.

For this method to apply, I *remove the `!/0`*, because declarative debugging works best on **pure** and **monotonic** logic programs. See [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity) for more information. Thus, we shall work on:

```
subset2([], []).
subset2([X|T], [X|T2]) :-
        subset2(T, T2).
subset2([_|T], [T2]) :-
        subset2(T, T2).
```

## Test cases

Let us first construct a test case that yields **unintended** answers. For example:

```
?- subset2([a], [a,b]).
false.
```

That obviously *not* intended. Can we *generalize* the test case? Yes:

```
?- subset2([a], [a,b|_]).
false.
```

So, we have now an infinite family of examples that yield wrong results.

**Exercise**: Are there also cases where the program is *too general*, i.e., test cases that *succeed* although they should fail?

## Locating mistakes

*Why* have we seen unintended failure in the cases above? To locate these mistakes, let us *generalize* the program.

For example:

```
subset2(_, []).
subset2([_|T], [_|T2]) :-
        subset2(T, T2).
subset2(_, [T2]) :-
        subset2(T, T2).
```

Even with this *massive* generalization, we *still* have:

```
?- subset2([a], [a,b|_]).
false.
```

That is, we have many cases where we *expect* the query to **succeed**, but it **fails**. This means that the remaining program, even though it is a massive *generalization* of the original program, is still **too specific**.

## Correcting the program

To make the shown cases succeed, we have to *either*:

- **add** clauses that describe the cases we need
- **or** *change* the existing clauses to *cover* these cases *too*.

For example, a way out would be to *add* the following clause to the database:

```
subset2([a], [a,b|_]).
```

We could even *generalize* it to:

```
subset2([a], [a|_]).
```

Adding either or both of these clauses to the program would make the query succeed:

```
?- subset2([a], [a,b|_]).
true.
```

However, that is of course *not* the general definition of `subset2/2` we are looking for, since it would for example still fail in cases like:

```
?- subset2([x], [x,y|_]).
false.
```

Therefore, let us go with the other option, and **correct** the existing definition. In particular, let us consider the last clause of the generalized program:

```
subset2(_, [T2]) :-
        subset2(T, T2).
```

Note that this **only** holds if the second argument is a list with **exactly one element** which is subject to *further constraints*. This seems *way too specific*!

Therefore, I recommend you start by changing this clause so that it at least makes the test cases collected so far all *succeed*. Then, add the necessary *specializations* to make it succeed *precisely* for the intended cases.

Comment: Mat, I think the subset was as it is (wrongly) written it was meant to be: subset2( Main_Set, Subset).What I mean is  that the second parameter should e the subset...  (so subset2([a], [a,b|_]). should fail...but not subset2( [a,b|_]),[a]).

Comment: In that case, simply swap the arguments of the test case: `subset2([a,b|_], [a])` **should succeed**, but **fails** currently. Then, apply the analysis I outline above. Also, to make your intention clearer, consider using a name like `set_subset/2`.

Comment: Hey guys, I know this is old but I forgot to tell you, coder is right. I just had to flip around the arguments and correct the unary list problem. My bad. Thank you!